# Getting "object variable or with block variable not set in excel vba"

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sheets("Translator 2 Weeks").Select
today = Date - 15
Dim MyRange As Range, cl As Range
Set MyRange = Range("a2").CurrentRegion
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lCol = lCol + 1

For Each cl In MyRange

 If ActiveCell.Column <= lCol Then
 If ActiveCell.Row <= lRow Then

Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=True).Activate


    If cl.Value <> Empty And IsDate(cl.Value) Then
    N = N + 1
    End If

End If

End If
Next cl
```

Getting error at line "Cells.Find()" Please help...
I am trying to find out the N number of cells used and only cells populated with date.

Comment: Excuse me for saying, but what exactly are you trying to do here ? can you explain ? Because your code and the way you tru to use the `Find` function is full with run-time errors, and too much use of `Activate`, `Select` etc...

Comment: The error you're getting is due to the `.Activate` - The `Find` doesn't return anything so there's no object and when trying to activate it obviously crashes. Other than that: What @ShaiRado says... It's quite unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: From what I can see he counts non-blank cells that contain date data.

Comment: Few more questions: Why do you calculate last row and column? From what I can see your table is within `.CurrentRegion`. Do you use `.Find` to activate next cell in a table? In every iteration you `Set cl = MyRange` though **MyRange** doesnt change. When check for `Value` in nested `If` you check whole table's value, not of the ActiveCell

Comment: Edit your question and describe what you are trying to do, this way someone (me, for example) might offer another way of solving a problem.

Comment: Am unable to edit the question.
Actually I am trying to get last column and row to find out the N number of cell used. 
Should I remove Activate, If I remove it, it throws an error.

Comment: @Shai Rado and AntiDrondert... Edited the question, please check and answer.